# While installing managed package into salesforce How could I enable-Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app

Tags: lightning, mobile, app, builder, experience

While installing managed package into salesforce How could I enable "Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app" .I need to make the plugin available in Lightning Experience. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

The availability of a managed package in Lightning Experience is determined by the content of the package itself. If you're installing a package from the AppExchange, if it has a tag of 'Lightning Ready' or 'Lightning App Builder' it will already be available for you when you install it.